# How to display GitHub pages correctly in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, github

I might be missing something really simple and huge, or probably the question has been already asked, but I was not able to find it.

It has been some time now that my Firefox is not able to display correctly any GitHub page, not even its home page. It looks to me as if the CSS is not considered at all.

Everything looks ok on IE and Chrome. Here's a sample screenshot:

[image]

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, Firefox v8.0 (but it happened on previous versions too).

PS I was only able to find [this unanswered question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.firefox/5tBNT7bsV_o) on google groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

- Clean your cache.
- Disable add-ons like Adblock Plus, Greasemonkey, etc.

Comment: 1) By 'clean your cache' do you mean the one fired by Ctrl+Shift+Canc shortcut?

2) Is there a way to make it work together with Adblock Plus?
Thanks

Comment: Ok, answer acknowledged! I allowed explicitly the whole GitHub in adblock, and that made it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem arose when it was using online certificate status protocol was enable.
Go to `Tool->Option->Advanced`, in certificate tab, by pressing validation button, disable OCSP.